# Why does "Recreational" have two definitions?

Tags: meaning, nuance

1.
of or relating to recreation :
recreational facilities in the park.

2.
(of a drug or medication) used for recreation and enjoyment rather than to treat a medical condition: recreational drugs such as marijuana and alcohol.

The second seems to simply imply association to drugs, but you still need to say "recreational drugs", and in that case the first definition means the same thing.

Am I missing something or is this just stupid?

Comment: Where did you find the definitions you cite?

Comment: *Recreational* is an adjective: your two definitions are for a noun, presumably *recreation,* in non-count and count senses respectively.

Comment: I'm dumb.
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recreational is the source, but I used recreation instead, without noticing...

Comment: With respect to facilities or policies or anything besides drugs, *recreational* contrasts with all other possible categories: legal, educational, residential, etc.; with respect to drugs, *recreational* contrasts specifically with *medical*.

Comment: Oooh. Odd. Is there a reason for that? Seems redundant and strange still.

Comment: There are hundreds of words in English that have multiple meanings/definitions.  Why ask specifically about this one?

Comment: @TrevorD - Hundreds??  I would guess there's in the neighborhood of ten thousand such multi-meaning words.

Comment: @HotLicks I was intentionally being conservative: I thought if I went too high someone would call me out on that!  And *thousands* is *hundreds of hundreds* - I just omitted how many hundreds! :-)

Comment: What is strange about this one is that the first definition plus a word means the same thing as the second definition, which cannot be used without that same word after. It is thoroughly redundant, or rather, it seems like it. As Stoney said, it only contrasts medical. Why? What purpose is there for that? Why is drug use a special case?

Answer (score 2):

The connotations of ***[recreation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=recreation)*** are very old and related. In the case of a drug, the idea is that of a substance taken for "personal pleasure",  not for medical treatment.

> - late 14c., ***"refreshment or curing of a person, refreshment by eating,"***  from Old French recreacion (13c.), from Latin recreationem (nominative recreatio) "recovery from illness,".
> - Meaning ***"refresh oneself by some amusement"*** is first recorded c. 1400.

Comment: Yeah, they are not two distinct definitions -- the second is merely an "interpretation" of the first, no different, really from "recreational rowing" vs rowing a whaling boat for a living.